Removing an li element and corresponding item from a java array list then output using ajax, javalin, html and css
we're having trouble to figure out how to remove an item that a user has searched for using our search bar. Our objective is to eliminate the item from our Java ArrayList and subsequently remove the corresponding list element (li element) from the displayed list of searched items below, by the user clicking onto a icon and without reloading the page.
-- Additional Information --
Display: We'll be utilizing Javalin for the presentation, where we'll format HTML into Java strings.
Preferably utilize AJAX.
--ONLY functional code--
Code No.1 (AJAX)
                $(document).on("click",".trashIcon",function()    {
                    $(this).closest('li').remove();
                })

Code No.1 removes the closest li element to the i element in it, when clicked.
--Other codes that does not function as intended or due to an error(such as syntax error)--
I tried implementing things such as mentioning a function inside the java and call that function while the page is posting, (Generated by ChatGPT For reference) However this was not possible due to the function not being clearly defined inside the app.java where i have Code No.2.
Additionally when the Code No.3 is implemented it would load up a blank page (which i assume is the URL stated inside Code No.4) without any HTML, CSS or JS when icon is clicked. Instead displays ONLY the array list with li element without any styles. In addition the java function removeCountry() did not execute when clicked
Code No.2 (Javalin/Java)
app.post("/removeCountry", Page2TA::removeCountry());
However this wasn't functioning due to removeCountry() being undefined
Code No.3(Javalin/Java) Altered Version of Code No.2:
app.post("/removeCountry", context => Page2TA.removeCountr(Context context));

Code No.4(AJAX code):
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Event listener for delete icon click
            $(document).on('click', '.delete-icon', function() {
                const countryToRemove = $(this).data('country');
                const $li = $(this).closest('li');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/removeCountry',
                    data: { country: countryToRemove },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $li.remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        })
</script>

Code No.5(Java function):
 public static void removeCountry(Context context, ArrayList<String> CountryOutput)   {
    String country = context.formParam("myCountry");
    CountryOutput.remove(country);
  }


It's not entirely clear (to me) what you are asking. It sounds as if you have a working solution - and are asking for suggestions on potentially "better" ways to do what already works ("is there any other ...way i could change the code...?"). If that is correct, then this question does not really fit on Stack Overflow (IMHO) and may be a better fir for Code Review - if you can make it more focused and relevant to that site.

If, however, you have a specific problem related to something which is not working, then what is the error/problem you are facing, and how can it be recreated using a [mre]? I would also recommend removing the background in the first 2 sentences in your question. It is not relevant to the problem you are facing (whatever that may be).

A more minor point: "Generated by ChatGPT" - I would not even mention that, since ChatGPT is quite capable of generating garbage, while presenting that garbage with a great deal of confidence.

Thank you very much for you feedback, first of all, all the code in Code No.2 and Code No.3 is not working. What I wanted to ask is if there's anyway of modify the code inside Code No.3 and execute the things that i have mentioned inside the description. As the code below did not work due to jumping to the  tied URL inside Code No.3 instead of staying inside the current page. Moreover it's not running the java method when run. Additionally ChatGPT was more for a reference as this is the first time i have coded in AJAX.
Sorry for the inconvenience.

You can [edit] your question. Also, what does "not working" mean? Be specific and precise. It's not clear at all (to me) what the problem is you are trying to solve. Maybe it will be clear to someone else...

After your edits... Your Code No.4 (AJAX code) looks reasonable (subject to testing). But your Javalin code looks very wrong. You can define a  route using something like post("/removeCountry", Page2TA::removeCountry) - and then provide that method in a class called Page2TA like this: public static void removeCountry(Context context) { ... }. Inside the { ... } you need to remove the "deleted" country record from wherever it is stored. Beyond that, I am not sure what the rest of your question is referring to. It all seems to be irrelevant.

Thank you very much, I would have a look into it. However I'm still not sure the parts you  are mentioning irrelevant, I assume it's the HTML part that I'm asking.

"the HTML part that I'm asking" - there is no HTML in your question, and no mention of any specific HTML-related problems you may be facing.  There is this "We'll be utilizing Javalin for the presentation, where we'll format HTML into Java strings", which I don't understand because why would you want to "format HTML into Java strings"? Anyway, I am sorry I could not help you much (or maybe at all).

You may use my code for your problem. I have written only client side code. Server side code is very simple you may use a plain servlet program and catch the parameter country and remove it from ArrayList. I have mainly concentrated on AJAX call using jQuery. Here is the code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.trashIcon {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.abc {
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
}



</style>
<body>
<ul id="countrylist" class="abc">
  <li>India</li>
  <li>Bhutan</li>
  <li>Nepal</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.abc li').click(function(e) 
   { 
      var countryToRemove=this.innerText;
       $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/removeCountry',
                    data: { country: countryToRemove },
                    success: function(response) {
                        this.remove();
                    }
                });
    
      
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

The easiest way of doing this work by AngularJS and Servlet. You may use this platform.
